# Defaulters prediction on next cycle

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models

I have data of loan installment repayments by customers, it contains all regular details like loan amount, last installment paid amount, next installments, credit score, age, region etc.

Along with all above details i have label on each customer as delinquent/non delinquent. But the delinq or non-delinq labeling has been done based on if customer paid for this month or not?

Now i am trying to predict that who will be the customers from the remaining data(who are non-deliquent this month) may turn delinquent next month.

My question is :
1) What is the best method to solve this problem?
2) To achieve best results, i can get the data image for past 12 Months(If time component to be used.)

Comment: Just another question to same problem is can we use LSTM for the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, your first port of call should be standard binary choice models. The 'silver bullet' in credit risk modelling is [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression). However, you can branch out and try generalised linear models with [probit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit_model) and [complementary log-log](http://www.stat.ualberta.ca/~kcarrier/STAT562/comp_log_log.pdf) link functions too. The benefits of these 'standard statistical methods' are:

1) Your model is easy to interpret. Model explainability is important in credit risk modelling.

2) You don't need vast amounts of data, as is the case with machine learning models.

3) Over sampling isn't required for standard statistical methods. In fact, over sampling will bias your model.

My recommendation is to avoid machine learning methods.

Another challenge is variable selection. Unfortunately, step-wise selection procedures are common place in credit risk modelling. These should be avoided all together - see Frank Harrel's objections [here](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/stepwise-regression-problems/).  A nice alternative is [Bayesian variable selection](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6175404/), or even [penalised regressions](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/36-classification-methods-essentials/149-penalized-logistic-regression-essentials-in-r-ridge-lasso-and-elastic-net/). Bayesian methods are nice since they let you elicit and incorporate expert knowledge about which variables are, and are not useful.

Comment: Thanks Ralph for the reply. I applied logistic regression with family binomial.  Here the problem i am facing is same set of customers on which the model is built this month, next month we will have same set of customers to predict the defaulters out of i.e. i have to do time based classification(the customers good this month may turn defaulters next month).

Comment: Say the current time is $t$. You can define your response $Y$ to be 1 if an account at time $t$ is 'bad' given they were 'good' at time $t-1$, and 0 otherwise. To me it sounds like you're trying to obtain a 'forward looking' estimate of the probability of default.

Comment: Thanks Ralph, got the point.. But the issue here is I have only 9000 customers.out of these those who turned bad in this month(not considering those who already bad in last month) will be very few..  So will that be a good idea to pickup such patterns from past few months? Though in this we will have multiple records of same customer..

Comment: Hi Ralph, I tried the model as per your suggestions but model is performing excessively poor and literally not able to capture the defaulters.. I tried GLM, KNN, NB and GBM. Any algorithm that might work well, you would like to suggest?